# How to animate, perform callback function, and then animate in sequence with React Native Animate?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation, react-animated

I'm using the [Animated library](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.56/animated) from react-native and I'd like to perform the following operation in this specific order

1. Fade Out
2. Perform Function Operation
3. Fade In

After reading the [react native animation documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/animations), I understand there is Animated.Sequence that combines animation in sequence, and also that [start takes a completion callback](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.56/animated#working-with-animations)

However the following code returns an error. See code below and [snack here](https://snack.expo.io/@cruzc09/fading-out-function)

```
Animated.sequence([Animated.timing(
  fadeAnim,
  {
    toValue: 0,
    duration: 1000,
  }
).start(PeformBetweenAnimations),
Animated.timing(
  fadeAnim,
  {
    toValue: 1,
    duration: 1000,
  }
)]).start();
```

Error

```
Cannot read property 'start' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of undefined
    at Object.start ([snack internals]
    at eval (module://App.js.js!transpiled:40:10)
    at Ra ([snack internals]
    at [snack internals]
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority ([snack internals]
    at lo ([snack internals]
    at Hs ([snack internals]
    at Ys ([snack internals]
    at ks ([snack internals]
    at https://snack.expo.io/web-player/37/static/js/2.3138b829.chunk.js:1:1021917
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore Animated.sequence and do something like this.

```
Animated.timing(this.fadeAnim, {
  toValue: 0,
  duration: 1000,
  useNativeDriver: true,
}).start(() => {
  // call your function here
  Animated.timing(this.fadeAnim, {
    toValue: 1,
    duration: 1000,
    useNativeDriver: true,
  }).start();
});
```